# How to display value in a td with a particular class name, by clicking in another td using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have to display contents in the cells of a table.

The table is as follow:

```
<table id="innertable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="tablewrapperheader">
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Date Requested</th>
                                <th>Date Time Range</th>
                                <th>Reason</th>
                                <th>Date Approved/Denied</th>
                                <th>Reason Denied</th>
                                <th>Approve/Deny</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td id="check" class="pending"><img src="../images/icons/36x36/exclamation.gif" alt="exclamation"/>
                                    &nbsp;<span id="checkMsg">Pending</span></td>
                                <td>06/15/2012</td>
                                <td>06/21/2012</td>
                                <td>Medical Checkups</td>
                                <td class="dateApproveDenied"></td>
                                <td class="reasonDenied"></td>
                                <td><img src="../images/icons/128x128/approve.png" class="actionApprove" alt="exclamation" height="16" width="16"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../images/icons/128x128/deny.png" class="actionDeny" alt="" height="16" width="16"/></td>
                            </tr>
```

User will click on active or deny and if the deny they have to give reason for denial. I have to display the date of denial and reason in the respected td for which i am using class names "dateApproveDenied" and "reasonDenied". I am using Jquery to achieve this affect but to no avail.

Here is my jquery

```
$(".actionDeny").click(function(){

    var reason = prompt("Write reason for denial.",'');
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //js months 0-11
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    }
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    }
    var today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
    $(this).closest('td .dateApproveDenied').text(today);
    $(this).closest('td .reasonDenied').text(reason);
});
```

I get the prompt for writing the reason but reason and dates are not appearing in the td. Can please somebody help me to set it right. Thanks

Comment: For starters, `reasonDenied` is an `id` but your jQuery selector is trying to find it as a `class`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have corrected it in my code and post as well .... but still i am not getting the values in td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use closest to get the parent tr, then find the tds.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.dateApproveDenied').text(today);
$(this).closest('tr').find('.reasonDenied').text(reason);
```

Edit

You can cache the closest selector as well:

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
$tr.find('.dateApproveDenied').text(today);
$tr.find('.reasonDenied').text(reason);
```